# Node.js parse returns undefined while it does receive JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse an incoming JSON object on my node.js server, yet it keeps saying it's undefined? Here is my code:

```
app.get("/adddates", function (req, res) {
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
console.log("does this get called?"); //Response 1 here is correct
    console.log(query); //Response here 2*
    console.log(query['name']); // Response 3 here is undefined?
if(query["Name"]!==undefined) {
    var tx = { Name : query["Name"], 
        Description: query["Description"],
        Date: query["Date"],
                    People: query["people"],
                    Tag: query["Tag"]

    };
            console.log(tx);
    todos.push(tx);
    console.log("Added " + tx.message);
    res.end("Todo added successfully");
}
else {
    res.end("Error: missing message parameter");
}
});

2* = { '[{"Name":"testetst","Description":"Blasts","Date":"2016-12-08","People":["Sjaak"],"Tag":"': '' }
```

So my question is, why is response 3 undefined and how to fix it otherwise?

Also why is the Tag value empty? The input is a hexcode color? Is it just a JSON parse i'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So your problem is that you have `Name` but read `name`?

Comment: the 2* string you show is an invalid or  only partial json. Can you post the complete json? Without seeing the rest of it my guess would be that the object is an array and you need something like `query[0]["Name"]`

Comment: This is a weird JSON if you see properly an object is visible in you #2 console where '[{"Name":"testetst","Description":"Blasts","Date":"2016-12-08","People":["Sjaak"],"Tag":"'  whole is the key and  " "  is value

Comment: The json is opening an array and then an object but these 2 never get closed with `}` and `]`, but looking at it you probably first need to select the first object of the array like this `query[0]` and then acces the properties on that like `query[0]["Name"]`

Comment: I tried doing the query[0]["Name"] part but then it returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined. The name/Name part also doenst work

Comment: the json you get as response seem incorrect. Its an object with the variable `[{"Name":"testetst","Description":"Blasts","Date":"2016-12-08","People":["Sjaak"],"Tag":"` and value `` (empty).

Comment: Ah yes! that must be the problem. the code to generate the JSON is:
    Dataarray.push(new Date(name, desc, date, PeopleArray, tag));



            var dateobj = JSON.stringify(Dataarray);
           console.log(dateobj);
            $.get( "http://localhost:3000/adddates",  dateobj  );

Sorry i'm new here cant get the code to properly indent

Comment: This construction seems really weird `new Date(name, desc, date, PeopleArray, tag)` for the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object in js. You'll probably just want to create a simple object like `{ "name": name, "Description": desc, "Date": date, "People": PeopleArray, "Tag": tag }`

Comment: I just used a basic constructor to make that object.
  '  function Date(name, Desc, date, people, tag) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Description = Desc;
    this.Date = date;
    this.People = people;
    this.Tag = tag;
}'

So that i can make multiple "dates"

Comment: Try passing in the array object instead of the json string. `$.get( "localhost:3000/adddates", Dataarray);`. There also seem to be a `;` to many in the original statement. Could you also post the result of `console.log(dateobj);`?

Comment: If i do that, the server says all is undefined, even the starting one. Also the JSON.stringy results in a valid JSON format, as tested with the site you sent me. So somehting must be going wrong in the middle

Comment: I've updated my answer with another possible fix and the reason why it probably doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm it seems like a good suggestion but it still gets butchered if i remove the tag
client side log:
'[{"Name":"werkt het nu eindelijk","Description":"wauw wat een tering bullshit","Date":"2016-12-07","People":["Sjaak"]}]'

Serverside log:
'{ '[{"Name":"werkt het nu eindelijk","Description":"wauw wat een tering bullshit","Date":"2016-12-07","People":["Sjaak"]}]': '' }'

There is no hashcode in there now right?

Comment: probably log the `req.url` that will give more answers :) (btw I'm from Belgium and can read the name and description ^^)

Comment: Hehe oops, that is just alot of built up frustration. But anyways, the url also looks kinda weird and i was wondering, is it becasue i built this different to string method?

 `Date.prototype.toString = function () {
    var ret = 'Name: ' + this.Name + ' Description:' + this.Description + ' on this date' + this.Date + ' People:' + this.People;
    return ret;
}; `

Comment: updated the answer again, I think it's now the complete story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [`url.parse`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) documentation you'll see this:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                    href                                     │
├──────────┬┬───────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────┤
│ protocol ││   auth    │      host       │           path            │ hash  │
│          ││           ├──────────┬──────┼──────────┬────────────────┤       │
│          ││           │ hostname │ port │ pathname │     search     │       │
│          ││           │          │      │          ├─┬──────────────┤       │
│          ││           │          │      │          │ │    query     │       │
"  http:   // user:pass @ host.com : 8080   /p/a/t/h  ?  query=string   #hash "
│          ││           │          │      │          │ │              │       │
└──────────┴┴───────────┴──────────┴──────┴──────────┴─┴──────────────┴───────┘
(all spaces in the "" line should be ignored -- they are purely for formatting)
```

so the `tag` in the json will become the hash after being send. To fix this the data you send should be url encoded. This can be done by [`encodeURIComponent(URI)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
$.get( "localhost:3000/adddates", encodeURIComponent(dateobj) );
```

**edit**
If you look at the [`query`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_urlobject_query) part you'll see it parses the data like `query=string`. So adding the query part to the url string:

```
$.get( "localhost:3000/adddates", "data=" + encodeURIComponent(dateobj) );
```

Then you should be able to retrieve the data like

```
var json = query["data"];
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var name = data[0]["Name"]
```

**original answer**

assuming the json is

```
[{"Name":"testetst","Description":"Blasts","Date":"2016-12-‌​08","People":["Sjaak‌​"],"Tag":""}]
```

There are different [sites](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) where you can validate if your json is correct.

then the query is an array of objects indicated by the `[` and `]`. To access the object itself you'll first need to get them from the array and then you'll be able to access the properties.

```
query[0]["Name"]
```

Comment: I tried that but then it gives me the TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined. Error.

Comment: It appears the JSON is not correct, but i can't find the error there.

    Dataarray.push(new Date(name, desc, date, PeopleArray, tag));



            var dateobj = JSON.stringify(Dataarray);
           console.log(dateobj);
            $.get( "http://localhost:3000/adddates",  dateobj  );

This is the code, but for some reason i can't indent it properly here, sorry im new to this site.

Comment: I'm answering the comments on you're question so you'll only have to look there. To add code snippets in a comment you surround it with  `. You can only actual format it in questions and answers.